# SSL certificate showing differently on digicert

Tags: iis, ssl, iis-6, ssl-certificate, digital-certificate

I have got two SSL Certificated installed on my server 2003 for differnt domains, for example *.test1.net and *.test2.net.

I assigned *.test1.net certificate to one of my website on IIS 6, www.test1.net, however when I check it on http://www.digicert.com/help/, it shows me that it is *.test2.net certificated used on www.test1.net not the correct one, I have no idea what's going on.

The certificate is definitely correct as it has been used for a month, but it goes wrong since this morning, please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been resolved by restarting the IIS service.

Answer (score 0):

You can't reliably use two certificates on the same IP and port. It just won't work because it requires [SNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) to work and there are still too many browsers out there that don't support SNI. The basic problem is that the server has to send the client a certificate before it knows what host name the client is trying to reach, so it has no way to know which certificate to send.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, but the service has been working well with two certificates for a year, but having issue suddenly

Comment: @Nick: As I said, you can't *reliably* use two certificates on the same IP and port.

Comment: Thanks @David Schwartz, I have checked the URL, they are using the same IP but different port number. Is there anything else that I can check?

Comment: Are you 100% sure you specified the right port in the two URLs?

Comment: I am sure.
Thanks for your help @David, the problem has been resolved by restarting the IIS service.

Comment: I do agree with David, why don't you purchase new IP and host each domain at dedicated ip?